# Show Manager in People Search Core Results

Tags: search-results, user-profile-property, people-search, managed-property, crawled-property

I need to show the manager (if possible clickable to his profile) on the People Search Core Results webpart.

What I've done atm:

1. Added a User profile property linked to the AD
2. Synchronised (and works because manager is filled in on user profile)
3. Added a Managed Property
4. Created a Crawled Property
5. Mapped Managed Prop to Crawled Prop
6. Full search crawl
7. Edited the XSL from Core Results webpart
8. Search for a user with manager

But the Manager won't show. (This works btw for other ones, I've added "Initials" for example)
If I alert on the manager in the XSL I get an empty value for the manager.

If there's more info you need... just say so.

**Update**
In the People Search Core Results webpart, the manager is also added in the Fetched Properties:

```
<Columns>
   <Column Name="Manager" HitHighLight="true"/>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my problem... Instead of a full crawl on the content source, I did an incremental crawl. Silly me... So it worked all along

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the column in the core results webpart properties?  There is a property where it's an xml document which says which columns to return in the search results.  Without your column being in that xml, that column won't appear in the data sent to the XSLT, and thus, you just getting an empty value in the XSLT transformation.

Comment: I guess you mean the "Fetched Properties" in the "People Search Core Results"-webpart? Yes, than:

<Columns>...<Column Name="Manager" HitHighLight="true"/>...</Columns>

Comment: Maybe it's because I've added the Manager properties the same way as for example the Initials? (Initials = text, Manager = person) Could this have something to do with it?